# Java AES encryption performance vs openssl performance

Tags: java, encryption, openssl

I've been measuring the performance of the java 11 built in AES-NI instructions and, with NI switched on through
`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS ->  -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UseAES -XX:+UseAESIntrinsics`
I run the benchmarks that are present in the open jdk itself through 

`java -server -jar target/jmh-jdk-microbenchmarks-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.openjdk.bench.javax.crypto.full.AESBench.encrypt  -p algorithm=AES/ECB/NoPadding`

When I compare the results and calculate the throughput in GB/s, for 16k encoding blocks, I get about 20% of the throughput when compared to the openssl performance test through
`openssl speed -evp aes-128-ecb`.

I don't seem to find a decent comparison/benchmark that describes which percentage of the maximum performance to expect with jdk 11, but 20 % seems rather low. Does anybody know of a comparison (or might have an idea where I go wrong, as these are off the shelf perf tools I would think not a lot can be tweaked there).

For reference, the openssl test reports this:

```
The 'numbers' are in 1000s of bytes per second processed.
type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes  16384 bytes
aes-128-ecb     825652.24k  3185957.03k  5251673.77k  5827996.33k  6027457.88k  6031906.13k
```

The openjdk benchmark reports this

```
Benchmark               (algorithm)  (dataSize)  (keyLength)  (provider)   Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
AESBench.encrypt  AES/ECB/NoPadding       16384          128              thrpt   40  84543.829 ± 9034.592  ops/s
```

Out of which I conclude that, for 16k blocks, the perf here is 85000 * 16k or about 1.4 GB/s, or about 20 % of the openssl number.

Is that expected or am I drawing the wrong conclusions?

Comment: Some regressions about the performances of jmh-jdk-microbenchmarks have been noticed recently: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213319 May you try an older version to get better results.

Comment: Another idea: the performances of any encryption algorithm using the ECB mode depends on the way multiple cores are used at the same time by the implementation. So, independently of the AES implementation, the way blocks are chained could affect the performances. If you have launched the tests on a processor with mutiple cores or threads, this could explain the differences. So, if you have not launched the openssl and java tests on a single core, try to do that and compare the results.

Comment: I tried launching the openssl test with -multi 1  (which is single core) and it did not make a difference. That said, I just tried using cryptsetup benchmark and then for aes-ebc 128 bit I get about 3.5 GB/s throughput. Still some way off, but I am starting to get suspicious about the reported throughput from openssl. Not sure how I could run the microbenchmark on a single core, do not see that option?

Comment: Maybe, for clarity, can you tell me how I could launch that jmh benchmark single core?

Comment: I do not know any option to do that, I usually run the tools in a VM that has only 1 core, therefore I'm sure that no multi-core optimization can occur.